# How can I mask a square image with a circle and also put a black border around the image

Tags: objective-c, ios, mask, uibezierpath

I have a square image 40x40 that I want to make round via clipping, but also put a black 5 pixel border around the image.

I have the following which is masking the square image so its now round

```
 UIImage *image = self.imageView.image;
        CGSize imageSize = image.size;
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.0);
        // Create the clipping path and add it
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:imageRect];
        [path addClip];


        [image drawInRect:imageRect];
        UIImage *roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        self.imageView.image = roundedImage;
```

But now I need to also add a round border around it. Do I need a new path or can I just tack onto the one one in the code above?

Comment: [imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [imageView.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
    [imageView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f]; What happens if you set border like this? Is it working?

Comment: This code adds a border to the `imageView`'s layer not to the clipped and contained image.

Comment: This will work if you set imgView.clipsToBounds = YES;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following three lines in your code (with whatever color and stroke width you want):

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]);
[path setLineWidth:50.0f];
[path stroke];
```

So it becomes:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.0);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// Create the clipping path and add it
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:imageRect];
[path addClip];
[image drawInRect:imageRect];

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]);
[path setLineWidth:50.0f];
[path stroke];

UIImage *roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.imageView.image = roundedImage;
```

Comment: Perfect! But set it to 5.0f instead of 50.0f.